# Passing string to input stream

Tags: java, inputstream

Someone wrote a class that I wish to test. It looks something like:

```
public class foo <E>{  
     public static void main(String[] args){
         Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
         do_stuff(scan.nextInt());
     }
}
```

I have another class which tries to test the above function's main method as follows:

```
public class Test{
   public static void main(String[] args){
        System.in.read("5".getBytes());
        foo.<Integer>main(new String[]{});
   }
}
```

Basically, I'm trying to use the Test class to feed input into the stream that will soon be read by the Scanner in foo. I cannot change foo at all, as it is someone else's code.

Why doesn't this work? What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: Can you call directly `doStuff` method? It is the one you should be testing, as there's no point to test something defined by the languaje. (It's like I would test if `+`operator works; that already got tested by languaje developers)

Comment: Also, you should look at [Junit](http://junit.org) or any other testing framework.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What your `System.in.read("5".getBytes())` does is pass a byte array to the `read` method, which attempts to fill it with user input. It completely ignores the data you put in that byte array.

You have to call `System.setIn()` to change the stream connected to `System.in`:

```
System.setIn(new ByteArrayInputStream("5".getBytes()));
foo.<Integer>main(new String[]{});
```